# Hide sample points in corner plot using corner.corner

Tags: python, emcee

In the context of Markov Chain Monte Carlo, I want to plot the 2D posterior distribution for a parameter estimation problem using `corner.corner`. The figure that I have now looks like this:

[image: example posterior pdf]

In the contour plot, the contours are defined by probability quantiles, such that what is outside the contours has low probability.

I would like to know if it is possible to remove the samples in the background (i.e. the grey dots) outside of the probability contours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the datapoints outside from contour, you have to `plot_datapoints=False` in corner.corner command.

I hope it will simply solve your issue.

Comment: This worked. I saw this kwarg in the corner.hist2d() function in the API documentation, but not for corner.corner. They must have forgotten to write it.